# DotNetNuke how do you add javascript or css file to content resource management?

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

Using dotnetnuke 7.0 community version.

I know how to add scripts/css to skin files, but I want to include them in the  tag of the entire system.

Looking at source, I see DNN attaches ?cdv=NUMBER to some of the scripts/css, that refers to the Content Resource Management version. I know how to increase that number too.

I want to use a jquery plugin on all my pages and I'd like to include it in the header AND to use the version number.

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Did my answer below resolve this for you?

Answer (score 8):

You would do this in your Skin file(s) and using the CRM registration tags

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API.aspx

Add something like the following to your SKIN

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>

<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="jquery.cycle.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

DNN should handle the rest of the details.

Comment: I'm having problems with the skin's javascript being added before DNN finishes registering things like ControlBar scripts and it's causing issues. Any way around this ?

Comment: Yes, you can set the priority/order see examples in https://github.com/ChrisHammond/HammerFlex/blob/master/Home.ascx